NameError: name 'process' is not defined
I have a base64 string with python function. I want to run this python code
My code:
import base64


def apply_script(custom_script: str, spark_df=None):
    script_encoded = base64.b64decode(custom_script).decode('utf-8')
    print(script_encoded)
    exec(script_encoded)
    print("EXECUTE: ")
    process(spark_df) # name "process" imported from exec() function
    return None


apply_script("aW1wb3J0IGpzb24KCgpkZWYgcHJvY2VzcyhkZik6CiAgICBwcmludCgiSGVsbG8gd29ybGQiKQogICAgcmV0dXJuIGRm")



I have the following output and error:
python test_custom_script.py
import json


def process(df):
    print("Hello world")
    return df
EXECUTE: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_custom_script.py", line 13, in <module>
    apply_script("aW1wb3J0IGpzb24KCgpkZWYgcHJvY2VzcyhkZik6CiAgICBwcmludCgiSGVsbG8gd29ybGQiKQogICAgcmV0dXJuIGRm")
  File "test_custom_script.py", line 9, in apply_script
    process(spark_df) # name "process" imported from exec() function
NameError: name 'process' is not defined


How to fix the error?

Don't you need to save somewhere the function that are introduced by exec()? Into some variable or something?

You have to add globals() to the exec method, so that it runs in the global scope:
def apply_script(custom_script: str, spark_df=None):
    script_encoded = base64.b64decode(custom_script).decode('utf-8')
    print(script_encoded)
    
    exec(script_encoded, globals()) # here
    
    print("EXECUTE: ")
    process(spark_df) # name "process" imported from exec() function
    return None


Welcome, please accept the answer if it answers your question :)
